# calling a SP which returns a long select return using LINQ

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I am calling a SP using linq and the SP returns a very long string. but when i receive the string its truncated. is there any way to increase the return length in linq?

Comment: linq does not defines the length of the string, have you defined the output parameter for the procedure.

Comment: nop, the stored proc returns the full string

Comment: What is it getting truncated to?

Comment: only a part of the string is being returned

Comment: how many characters get returned?

Answer (score 1):

This may not be an issue with LINQ to SQL. It may have to do with how you declared the variable containing the output of the stored procedure inside the sproc itself.

Another possibility could be that stored procedure variable was changed after your DBML and entity classes where created. In other words, you could have varchar(100) in your LINQ and varchar(200) in your stored proc. If this is the case, you need to regenerate your DBML.